# Android - back navigation from activity to previous one (no back arrow)

Tags: android, android-intent, toolbar

I have 2 activities: `HomeActivity` and `EmailChangeActivity` and some fragment inside `HomeActivity`. What I want to do is to set `back navigation arrow` in `EmailChangeActivity` toolbar. I have more activities and somehow I managed to make that arrow (but I made `Intents` straight from activities, not from fragment inside activities). What I did in order to get that arrow was:

When I go to `EmailChangeActivity` from `HomeActivity` I call this in `HomeActivity` fragment:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            ChangeEmailActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Inside `EmailChangeActivity` I insert standard code creating `Toolbar` and setting it:

```
// Setting Toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.change_email_activity_name));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In `Manifext.xml` I made:

```
 <!-- Home Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/home_activity_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Normal">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

<!-- Change Email Activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.ChangeEmailActivity"
    android:label="@string/register_activity_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Normal"
    android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.nazwamarki.myapplication.HomeActivity" />

</activity>
```

Still got no result. Any help?

**Edit**

I forgot to add that I also included in `EmailChangeActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using an `ActionBarActivity`:

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // The intent to go back to HomeActivity
    }
});
```

If you *are* using an `ActionBarActivity`, then all you need to do is make Android use the Toolbar as an ActionBar.

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: But what If i start activity not using `startActivity()` but `startActivityForResult()`? Does is change sth?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing this part:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

You can get more details on this here [Android Developers- Providing up navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)